# Common way to access database in Android

Tags: android, android-sqlite

I have five tables in my database. They are managed by a class called DBHelper, which extends the SQLiteOpenHelper class. Therefore this class only cares for

> database creation and version management

(http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteOpenHelper.html).

I need to query, insert and modify data not only in one activity but in several ones. I tsuppose it's not good practice to execute SQL statements everywhere in your code. I though about encapsulation and created a class which provides many static methods that return or modify data in the database. By now this class gets too long.

What is the best way to organize your database accesses? One class for all possible SQL statements? Or were I mistaken by supposing that scattered SQL statements throughout the app do not represent good coding style?

Thanks

Comment: use a custom ContentProvider

Comment: but i never want to share data with other applications.

Comment: i know,  make it not exported then

Answer (score 0):

You may separate the data access code into separate entity specific classes and these classes in turn could use the SQLiteOpenHelper
You may also defined DAO ( data only classes) for both way data communication between these entity classes and business logic classes

Answer (score 0):

This is how I do it.. Everything in one place, and you just have to make MyDatabase object and call whatever method you want from your code. 
Make sure to read about update, insert and delete (special wrapped queries).. You can also execute raw sql statements. Hope I wasnt to confusing ;)

```
public class MyDatabase {

    public static final String DB_NAME = "myname.db";
    public static final int DB_VERSION = 1;
    public static final String MY_TABLE = "my_table";

    public static final String E_IDD = "idd";
    public static final String E_FIELD1 = "f1";
    public static final String E_FIELD2 = "f3";
    public static final String E_FIELD3 = "f3";

    Context context;
    MyDbHelper dbHelper;
    SQLiteDatabase db;

    public MyDatabase(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
        dbHelper = new MyDbHelper();
    }


    public void insertSomeObject(Object obj) {

        db = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();

        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();

        values.put(E_IDD, obj.getId());
        values.put(E_FIELD1, goal.getField1());
        values.put(E_FIELD2, goal.getField2());
        values.put(E_FIELD3, goal.getField3());


        db.insertWithOnConflict(MY_TABLE, null, values,
                SQLiteDatabase.CONFLICT_IGNORE);
    }

    public void deleteObject(int id) {
        db = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
        db.delete(MY_TABLE, E_IDD + "=?",new String[] {""+id });
    }

    public Object fromCursor(Cursor c) {
//carefull here to match the exact types you need for your object
        Object obj = new Object(c.getInt(0), c.getInt(1), c.getString(2), c.getInt(3))

        return obj;
    }

    public ArrayList<Object> query() {
        ArrayList<Object> objArray = new ArrayList<Object>();

        db = dbHelper.getReadableDatabase();

        Cursor cursor = db.query(MY_TABLE, null, null, null, null, null,
                null);

        if (cursor.getCount() <= 0)
            return null;

        cursor.moveToFirst();
        goalArray.add(fromCursor(cursor));
        while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
            objArray.add(fromCursor(cursor));
        }
        return objArray;
    }

    class MyDbHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

        public MyDbHelper() {
            super(context, DB_NAME, null,
                    DB_VERSION);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
            String sql = String.format("create table %s "
                            + "(%s int primary key, " + "%s int, " + "%s text, "
                            + "%s int)",
                    MY_TABLE, E_IDD, E_FIELD1, E_FIELD2, E_FIELD3);
            db.execSQL(sql);
        }

        @Override
        public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
            db.execSQL("drop if exist " + MY_TABLE);
            //or do something smarter 
            onCreate(db);
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Also when I'm writing Object, i think you need to write your own class to be your Data model for example : public class MyObjectForMyDB{ int id; String field1, int field2 etc...}

Comment: Thanks, i'll have a look at your approach. But it looks good!

Comment: Cool, let me know if it helped :) And if you need any help. Cheers!

Comment: But all these methods that are supposed to change the database could be static!? So actually it's nearly the same approach which I used earlier on: one class that organizes database access.

Comment: Why should they be static? I usually extend the Application class, and open my db there, and write a static MyDatabase getDb()...

Comment: i totaly missunderstood your question, i'm sorry. P.S. I am facing the exact same organisation issue at this moment .. Perhaps the best solution is to make some kind of Wrapper function, for similar queries like ArrayList<Object> getQuery(int type) and setup a array of objects that will describe all you need for your query, table names, where strings etc